# Wordpress Custom Post Type - Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom theme and have added a few custom post types to it. For each custom post type I need to choose a specific set of custom fields each time I am making a new post in either section.

For example, I have the custom post type "Motors" for displaying the details of cars. Each time I add a new car using this custom post type I have to manually select the same set of custom fields and fill them in (Mileage, Fuel Type, Colour etc).

Is it possible to create a custom meta box for my Motors custom post type that uses the Wordpress custom fields? And can I have it automatically list out the 5 or so custom fields I always choose and simply require me to input a value for each before publishing?

Comment: This post should contain what you're looking for: http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I would recommend using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

This is essentially what WordPress custom fields *should* be. It lets you add any number of custom fields, including text, textareas, images, etc. to specific post types, page types, etc. and would be ideal for what you are describing.

Comment: Perfect! I was hoping to do this without using a plugin, this is plugin is just so good I would be stupid not to use it. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I try to avoid plugins, but this is ideal for most cases. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code. It will add a text box which allows to enter a image url that will display in the post. Use this below code and change your post type accordingly. Also you can any number of fields you want.

```
add_action('admin_init','add_metabox_post_banner_image_widget');
add_action('save_post','save_metabox_post_banner_image_widget');

/*
* Funtion to add a meta box to enable banner image widget on posts.
*/
function add_metabox_post_banner_image_widget()
{
  add_meta_box("banner_image", "Enable Banner Image", "enable_post_banner_image_widget", "post", "normal", "high"); /* replace "post" with your custom post value(eg: "motors") */
}

function enable_post_banner_image_widget(){
 global $post;

 $image=get_post_custom($post->ID );
//print_r($image);

 $banner_image_src = $image['post_banner_image_src'][0];

?>

<label for="post_banner_image_src">Banner Image Url:</label>
<input type="text" name="post_banner_image_src" id="post_banner_image_src" value="<?php if($banner_image_src!=''){echo $banner_image_src; } ?>" >
<p><em>Example: https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/google.jpg</em></p>

<?php
}

/*
* Save the meta box value of banner image widget on posts.
*/
function save_metabox_post_banner_image_widget($post_id)
{
// Bail if we're doing an auto save
if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

// if our current user can't edit this post, bail
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

$banner_image_src = isset($_POST['post_banner_image_src']) ? $_POST['post_banner_image_src']:'';

update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_banner_image_src', $banner_image_src );

}
```

Comment: this code is very helpful just write comments so developer can understand which args use for which option and thank you:)